# ZeroDivisionError: Inverse does not exist

Tags: sage

The problem is 2 is non invertible at Integer Mode Ring (6). I would like to divide the result into 2 as an ordinary integer. In another word, I like to escape from integer mode ring's trap and bring the result to ordinary integer and then divide it into 2.

```
def fast_exponentiation(c, L, q):
    Zq = IntegerModRing(q) # create Z_q
    g2 = c 
    result = 1
    while True:
        y = L % 2
        result = Zq(result) * Zq(g2 ** y)
        g2 = Zq(g2 * g2)
        L = L >> 1
        if L == 0:
            break
    return result

e = fast_exponentiation(2, 4, 6) 
print e / 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to turn `e` into an `Integer` again, you have a few options: call `Integer` (the target object), or `ZZ` or `IntegerRing`, the target parent.

```
sage: e
1
sage: parent(e)
Ring of integers modulo 6
sage: ZZ(e)
1
sage: parent(ZZ(e))
Integer Ring
```

And so:

```
sage: e = ZZ(e)
sage: e/2
1/2
sage: e//2
0
```

or whatever else you'd like.